# HOw do you email through the linux commandline?

Tags: email, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 9, what is the best way to send a file though an email using the commandline?

Comment: flagged for move to serverfault.org -- but I think you want uuencode/uudecode for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work.. don't know if it's the best way but it's certainly straightforward.

```
mail -s "subject here" recip@domain.com < /path/to/file
```